# I want to dynamically change the lookup columns in look up transformer in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I just want to map dynamically  lookup column in LOOKUP Transform SSIS

In my task that look up column will all ways change 
For Example:

````````
TableA 
```````
Col1    |   Col2    |   Col3
--------+-----------+---------
1       |   2       |   3
2       |   1       |   4
3       |   2       |   1
````````

This time lookup columns are Col1+Col2 
Next day it will change to Col2+Col3

I want to map dynamic input column with ssn

[image]

Comment: PLs Any One can help me on this

Comment: What determines what those lookup columns will be from one day to the next?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the lookup columns are defined from one day to the next, it may be easier to make the query in the Lookup transformation dynamic instead.  Check out the following link:

https://suneethasdiary.wordpress.com/2011/12/28/creating-a-dynamic-query-in-lookup-transformation-in-ssis/

Comment: yes the columns are defined dynamically ...here i wan to know how can i dynamically map lookup column (i.e Arrow mark from input column to lookup column)

Comment: I do not see a way to dynamically set up the column mapping under a single Lookup Transformation.  However, if you know what the column option sets are going to be and the rules governing which sets to apply from one day to the next, then you can set up a decision process in the data flow path that can apply one of several Lookup Transformations where each applies a different set of columns in the mapping.

Comment: Two other options are provided in the following link on StackOverflow.  You can set up and apply a custom table in the database that defines the column set options or use a script task:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107916/ssis-dynamic-column-mappings

Comment: And the following link provides some coding that can be applied in a script task:https://munishbansal.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/dynamic-columns-mapping-%e2%80%93-script-component-as-destination-ssis/  Try running some searches in google using "ssis lookup transformation dynamic mapping".  There are quite a few write-ups available on the internet for what you want to accomplish.

Comment: And yet another alternative approach to consider:  http://zahidbi.com/2011/04/19/dynamic-column-mapping-in-ssis-part-2-using-dts-variable/